# Do I have to create extension on every connect to database?

Tags: postgresql

I want to use `uuid_generate_v4` in PostgreSQL. I am currently using version 11, but plan to upgrade to 12.
When I try to call the function I get this error after every connect:

```sql
test=# SELECT uuid_generate_V4();
ERROR:  function uuid_generate_v4() does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT uuid_generate_V4();
```

And I have to rerun:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
```

Minimum "working" example

```sql
CREATE DATABASE test;
\connect test;
SELECT uuid_generate_V4(); -- Fails makes sense
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
SELECT uuid_generate_V4(); -- Works
\connect postgres --- Close connection to test
\connect test; 
SELECT uuid_generate_V4(); -- Fails makes no sense
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
SELECT uuid_generate_V4(); -- Works
```

Do I really need to add/create the extension at every connect or am I doing something wrong? 
I have the same problem with other extensions as well, but uuid is the most crucial to get working.

Comment: It seems you did not `commit` the `create extension`. Did you maybe turn off auto-commit? Also: if you always want that in all databases in the future, you can add those extensions to the `template1` database

Comment: I have not turned off auto-commit to my knowledge, but I will check @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: hmm that seems to be the issue yes... But I don't know how I turned it off XD